# How can I solve Angular CLI ng new error?

Tags: json, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to install new Angular project using angular/cli commmand:

```sh
ng new app-name
```

My tools are:

```
ng --version

Angular CLI: 8.2.2
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.802.2
@angular-devkit/core         8.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.2.2
@schematics/angular          8.2.2
@schematics/update           0.802.2
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

So, in order to get the default angular app I run:

```
ng new app-name
```

Choose adding routing and CSS fro the styles.

I get the following output:

```sh
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...pes/gulp":"3.X","@typ'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gusenica\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-20T15_56_11_846Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Question is how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `@angular/cli`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was some kind of npm-related problem.  I just ran

```sh
npm cache clean --force
```

and it worked!